# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection Console error in react native

Tags: react-native

I am stuck with a react Native error on my console. I don't understand where the error is coming from :

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):

[ClientError: Unable to parse value of "$id=undefined". Please quote string values.]
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
[ClientError: Unable to parse value of "$id=undefined". Please quote string values.]
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
[ClientError: Unable to parse value of "$id=undefined". Please quote string values.]
```

At first I received a console warning on using props which was solved but now I am stuck with a warning on my school thats impacting my project completion, Please Help.

I am using Sanity as my backend.
Should I use React-redux to solve this ?